# Error when calling Create Contact in the Exact Target rest api

Tags: rest-api

I'm having trouble creating a new contact with the Exact Target rest api
https://www.exacttargetapis.com/contacts/v1/contacts

When posting the following json object to the api

```
{
    "contactKey":"3240dd71@Test.com",
    "attributeSets":[
        {
            "name":"Email Addresses",
            "items":[{
                    "values":[{
                            "name":"Email Address",
                            "value":"3240dd71@Test.com"
                        },{
                            "name":"HTML Enabled",
                            "value":true
                        }]}]}]
}
```

The response I get back is

```
{
    "operationStatus":"OK",
    "rowsAffected":0,
    "contactKey":"3240dd71@Test.com",
    "contactID":163394869,
    "contactTypeID":0,
    "isNewContactKey":true,
    "requestServiceMessageID":"82f8cb91-da83-459b-b56d-8f6c33b09d5b",
    "hasErrors":true,
    "resultMessages":[
        {
            "resultType":"Operational",
            "resultClass":"Error",
            "resultCode":"",
            "resultName":"",
            "message":"An exception occurred while processing the request item @ Index #0. [ReferenceID: 90082a2b-fe00-4efa-92ee-b203b768211e]"
        }
    ],
    "serviceMessageID":"07a4536b-5a19-48d4-886d-a27c608f1ddb"
}
```

Any ideas what the problem might be?

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce marketing cloud restful api is not mature enough.

That's why it doesn't have a proper error messages.

I've been through the same issue with something@example.com.

It's all about the domain, I changed the email's domain into my company's domain and succeeded.